# Power BI - Converting date to a ascending whole number unique by country

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have below sample data

```
Country     Case    Date
Austalia    80      22/01/2020
Austalia    100     23/01/2020
Austalia    1200    25/01/2020
Austalia    1500    27/01/2020
America     22      18/02/2020
America     101     22/02/2020
America     200     23/02/2020
America     2100    28/02/2020
Canada      100     24/02/2020
Canada      1200    12/03/2020
Canada      1500    26/03/2020
Canada      1600    27/03/2020
Germany      99     12/01/2020
Germany      100    18/01/2020
Germany      101    19/01/2020
Germany      102    20/01/2020
France       102    13/03/2020
France       304    16/03/2020
France       504    18/03/2020
France      2455    20/03/2020
France      3455    25/03/2020
```

I want to have one more column say "Day" which has value based on below criteria.

## For each case value greater then 99, the day column start with 0 and value ascends based on date (unique for each country). Like for country - Australia above, the day column will have value in each row as null, 0, 2, 4

My final table should be like below

```
#Country    Case    Date         Day
Austalia    80      22/01/2020   null
Austalia    100     23/01/2020   0
Austalia    1200    25/01/2020   2
Austalia    1500    27/01/2020   4
America      22     18/02/2020   null
America     101     22/02/2020   0
America     200     23/02/2020   1
America    2100     28/02/2020   6
Canada      100     24/02/2020   0
Canada      1200    12/03/2020   17
Canada      1500    26/03/2020   31
Canada      1600    27/03/2020   32
Germany       99    12/01/2020   null
Germany      100    18/01/2020   0
Germany      100    19/01/2020   1
Germany      102    20/01/2020   2
France       102    13/03/2020   0
France       304    16/03/2020   3
France       504    18/03/2020   5
France      2455    20/03/2020   7
France      3455    25/03/2020   12
```

Thanks If someone can help how to create a PowerBI measure or DAX function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some DAX that I worked out for you:

```
DayFromCaseCount99 =
VAR ZERODATE =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Country] ),
        'Table'[Case] > 99
    )
VAR DAYS =
    DATEDIFF ( ZERODATE, CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ) ), DAY )
RETURN
    IF ( MAX ( 'Table'[Case] ) > 99, days, "n/a" )
```

First I calculate the earliest date by country where number of cases is more than 99.  Then I calculate the number of days between the biggest date in our filter context.  Finally I display the result, again, only for the rows where Case is greater than 99.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used powerBI's 'column from example' when transforming the dates and it looks like it did some funny things.  Sorry the output doesn't quite match your example, but I think the calculation is still good.

Comment: Many many thanks Ryan :) It worked, though I have to put some other value 999 instead of "n/a" as it was giving error (Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.) which resulted in giving negative values instead of having "n/a" . Like first row instead of n/a now it has -6 . My problem is solved though.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column and use this DAX code:

```
Day = 
VAR __country = 'Table'[Country]
VAR __subTable = FILTER( 'Table'; 'Table'[Country] = __country )
VAR __minDate = CALCULATE( MIN( 'Table'[Date] ); __subTable; 'Table'[Value] >= 100 )
VAR __result = DATEDIFF(__minDate; 'Table'[Date]; DAY )
Return IF( 'Table'[Value] < 100; BLANK(); __result )
```

You should be able to get the next results

[image]

Comment: Hi Agustin, your solution gives error in this row "VAR __minDate = CALCULATE( MIN( 'Table'[Date] ); __subTable; 'Table'[Value] >= 100 )" as "A single value of the column "Date"  in table cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min,max,count, or sum to get a single result.         Although If i remove __subtable from tha row, I get the values in Day Column but all as 0 instead of ascending order.